# SQL Server Express, Local DB and SQL Server CE and Windows Azure Auto-sync

Tags: azure, sql-server-ce, azure-sql-database, sql-server-express, localdb

Forgive me I am not a developer. I have seen tones of post regarding these three little monsters but still get confused in what to use. Here is my use case:

I have a WPF application that runs in client. A location that will have a Master client machines and a few slaves machines containing the same app. The slave applications writes to the master DB through a web service (IIS required). The Master DB will then sync with windows Azure with the build in auto sync feature. Here comes to my questions:

Which DB I should use in order to:

1. being easily installed in the client, i.e. if you would say SQL Server Express, can we package both IIS, SQL Server Express and my WPF applications into a single package for easy installation in client side?
2. able to use the Azure auto sync feature - can localDB do so?
3. license free to the client end users - heard that SQL Server Express has a 10GB limit to the client or otherwise a license fee has to be paid, is that true?

Thank you.

Comment: **LocalDB** is a developer-friendly version of SQL Server **Express**, and yes, the Express edition (as of 2008 R2) has a 10 GB size limit. SQL Server Express needs to be separately installed (it's a **server**, after all). SQL Server CE (Compact Edition) is a totally different story - it's an "embedded" database, you basically just ship a few DLLs - but it's designed for single-user mode, not intended as a server.

Comment: Does LocalDB also has a 10GB size limit? Could it be installed together with the APP? Could it be synced using the Azure Auto Sync?

Comment: Since LocalDB **is** SQL Server Express - yes, the same size limit applies. And since it's a server-based product, it needs to be installed separately (can be downloaded from Microsoft Download site)